# What is meant by spin temperature in the context of ultrafast demagnetization's three-temperature model?

Tags: electrons, temperature, quantum-spin, spin-models

Ultrafast demagnetization and associated fields often refer to the three-temperature model introduced by [Beaurepaire](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.76.4250). As the abstract says:

> The relaxation processes of electrons and spins systems following the absorption of femtosecond optical pulses in ferromagnetic nickel have been studied using optical and magneto-optical pump-probe techniques. The magnetization of the film drops rapidly during the first picosecond, but different electron and spin dynamics are observed for delays in the range 0–5 ps. The experimental results are adequately described by a model including three interacting reservoirs (electron, spin, and lattice).

I understand the lattice temperature to be the familiar macroscopic temperature, and the electron temperature to be defined by the spread of the electron distribution around the chemical potential (with the spin-resolved chemical potential increasing or decreasing with temperature depending on the density of states for reasons that I also quite can't grasp):

[image: Plot of Fermi-Dirac distribution for different temperatures]

But I have trouble undestanding the spin temperature. [Temperature for a dynamic spin ensemble](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.82.031111) clarified that we are talking about the atomic spins, the total spin of the electrons bound to each atom:

[image: Temperature equation]

$\mu_s$ is the strength of the random exchange field acting on each spin. As I understand, the concept seems to quantify the fluctuations in the direction of the magnetization. Then it would be different from the concept of magnon temperature I also came across, in that we are talking here about incoherent fluctuations. (Although now it makes me question whether lattice temperature and phonon temperature are also different…)
I'm guessing that at thermal equilibrium, the spin fluctuations are caused by the heat of the lattice: the changing distances between atoms change the exchange field, which changes the quantization direction of the spins.

But after optical excitation, I don't understand how the spin temperature can evolve independently from the electron temperature. Since the atomic spin is the sum of the bound electrons spins, if the electrons are excited in a spin-conserving way, the $S_i$ shouldn't change.
Does that mean that an increase of the spin temperature characterizes how many electrons have flipped their spin?

But I remember a models of the demagnetization using a single electron temperature for electrons of both spins, which means that their distribution stayed the same, which means that there can't be a net flipping of the spins. [This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-63452-3/) even mentioned that the electron and spin temperature generally both increase together.

What's more, it seems to be the spin temperature which drives the demagnetization, for example in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep04658):

> The absorption of a strong laser pulse results in a quasi-instantaneous increase of the electronic temperature. The energy is rapidly transferred to the spin bath leading to the fast drop of the magnetic signal.

But demagnetization doesn't sounds like an incoherent process like the above equation for the spin temperature suggests. If I add random noise to a fixed magnetization, I'm expecting the random noise to cancel out over the whole sample, so no demagnetization (as long as the spin temperature stays under the Curie temperature).
What am I missing?